# An elegant way to group parent and children to List[(Parent, List[Child])]

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have some structure like so:

```
case class Parent(id : Option[Long], name : String)
case class Child(id : Option[Long], parentId : Long, name : String)

val parents : List[Parent] = List(
  Parent(Some(1),"John"), 
  Parent(Some(2),"Jake"), 
  Parent(Some(3),"Tamara"))

val children : List[Child] = 
List(Child(id = Some(1), parentId = 1, name = "John I"),
     Child(id = Some(2), parentId = 1, name = "John II"),
     Child(id = Some(3), parentId = 1, name = "John III"),
     Child(id = Some(4), parentId = 2, name = "Jake I"),
     Child(id = Some(5), parentId = 2, name = "Jake II"),
     Child(id = Some(5), parentId = 3, name = "Tamara I")
    )
```

How can I write a function that results in this?

```
List(
(Parent(Some(1),"John"), List(Child(id = Some(1), parentId = 1, name = "John I"),Child(id = Some(2), parentId = 1, name = "John II"),Child(id = Some(3), parentId = 1, name = "John III"))),
(Parent(Some(2),"Jake"), List(Child(id = Some(4), parentId = 2, name = "Jake I"),Child(id = Some(5), parentId = 2, name = "Jake II"))),
(Parent(Some(3),"Tamara")), List(Child(id = Some(5), parentId = 3, name = "Tamara I"))),
)
```

I have this already :

```
  def groupParentChildren(parents : List[Parent], children : List[Child]) : List[(Parent, List[Child])] = {

children
  .groupBy(_.parentId)
  .map{case(parentId, children) => (parents.find(p => p.id.get == parentId), children)}
  .toList
  .flatMap{case(parentOpt, childrens) => parentOpt.map(parent => (parent, childrens))}
}
```

It seems to do the job, but is there a more elegant way to achieve the result in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most elegant is:

```
parents.map {
  case p@Parent(Some(pid), _) => (p, children.filter(_.parentId == pid))
  case p => (p, Nil)
}
```

But that does do a lot of unnecessary scanning of `children`. Slightly more efficient is:

```
val childrenByParentId = children.groupBy(_.parentId)
parents.map {
  case p@Parent(Some(pid), _) => (p, childrenByParentId.getOrElse(pid, Nil))
  case p => (p, Nil)
}
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about `@` being used this way if we are going to use the object.